# Redirect page after all nodes save

Tags: 7

I am trying to write a custom module to save special nodes.
With my code after first node save, page redirect and other not affected.

I need after all nodes_save redirect to list.

```
$nidew = [12,34,55,12,66,63];
foreach ($nidew as $nodeuniqe) {
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $node = node_load($nodeuniqe); 
    node_save($node);
    drupal_goto('list');
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please give more context and also explain what is not working in your current code.

Comment: @berliner my code just first node saved and go redirect before all node save, i want node_save all nodes in $nodeuniqe after that redirect to "list"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a simple PHP issue and you wnt to take the redirect command out of the foreach loop e.g.:

```
$nidew = [12,34,55,12,66,63];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  foreach ($nidew as $nodeuniqe) {
    $node = node_load($nodeuniqe); 
    node_save($node);
  }
  drupal_goto('list');
}
```

Comment: not work ! drupal_goto('list'); should in "IF"

Comment: You'd move the if statement above the forach loop then. I've updated my example

Comment: Thanks man.....